# Apache Not Starting Up OSX 10.6.7

Tags: mysql, apache, macos, terminal

This is driving me nuts! New computer, not two days old, fresh install of OS x 10.6.7.

I checked in system preferences > Sharing > Web sharing: On

When I go to: http://192.168.1.13/ or http://192.168.1.13/~gorteks/ the message says:

`Safari can’t open the page “http://192.168.1.13/~gorteks/” because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again."`

In Terminal I tried typing in: `$ sudo apachectl configtest`

The error comes back as: `httpd: Syntax error on line 493 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+entropy-php.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _libiconv\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/lib/libintl.8.dylib\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib\n`

Everyone, I have no idea how to fix this as I am such a noob to all of this. Can anyone shed some light to this issue? Much appreciated!!

Dd

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use MAMP http://www.mamp.info It is a Apache+PHP+MySQL already configured solution. It is highly recommended to use.

On the other hand, it says there's a syntax error in `httpd.conf` file. It must be under `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Can you post that file somewhere and then try to fix error around line 493.

Comment: I have loaded MAMP. Works fine but not sure where to place my working files, view my working files etc. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

Comment: You can choose it from Preferences button in MAMP window.(Apache->Document root) Please mark this answer as correct if you think so.